# Update response succefully but does not update table

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

I am developing app in android. From there I want to update my **Email** in  table.My

database is in MySQL.

**I checked my PHP code by excuting it in browser.**

**It works fine and update my database but when**

**i run file with android it doesnot update table**

**but return reponse successfuly Updates**

My Android Code

```
/**
 * Background Async Task to Create new product
 * */
class UpdateEmail extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(edit_profile.this);
    pDialog.setMessage("Updating....");
    pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
    pDialog.setCancelable(true);
    pDialog.show();

}

/**
 * Creating product
 * */
protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

    // Building Parameters
    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

    String abc= email_edit_view.getText().toString();
    SessionSharedPrefences.setUserEmail(getApplicationContext(), abc);
    Log.i("email_edit_view", abc);
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Email", "abc@gmail.com"));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("U_ID", SessionSharedPrefences.getUserEmail(getApplicationContext())));


    // getting JSON Object
    // Note that create product url accepts POST method
    JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(update_url_email_information   ,"POST", params);

    // check log cat fro response
    Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

    // check for success tag
    try 
    {
        int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

        if (success == 1) 
        {
            Log.i("sucessssssssss", "sucess");
            // closing this screen
        } 
        else
        {
            // failed to create product

        }
    }
    catch (JSONException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }

    return null;
}

/**
 * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
 * **/
protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
    // dismiss the dialog once done
    if (pDialog.isShowing()) {
        pDialog.dismiss();
        // progressDialog.setCancelable(true);

        }

    }

}
```

My PHP File is.

```
<?php


// array for JSON response
$response = array();
// check for required fields

if (isset($_POST['U_ID']) &&  !empty($_POST['U_ID'])&& isset($_POST['Email'])  && !empty($_POST['Email']) ) {
 $U_ID = $_POST['U_ID'];
    $Email_id = $_POST['Email'];

    // include db connect class
    require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';

    // connecting to db
    $db = new DB_CONNECT();

 //$result = mysql_query("UPDATE `user` SET `Email_id`='$Email_id' WHERE `U_id`= '$U_ID'");
$result = mysql_query("UPDATE `smartshoppingsystem`.`user` SET `Email_id` = '$Email_id' WHERE `user`.`U_id` ='$U_ID'");
    // check if row inserted or not
    if ($result) {
        // successfully inserted into database
        $response["success"] = 1;
        $response["message"] = "Data successfully Updates.";

        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
    } else {
        // failed to insert row
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Oops! An error occurred.";

        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
    }

} else {
    // required field is missing
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

My Json Java File is:

```
public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }

    // function get json from url
    // by making HTTP POST or GET method
    public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
            List<NameValuePair> params) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {

            // check for request method
            if(method == "POST"){
                // request method is POST
                // defaultHttpClient
                Log.d("JSONParser","POST METHOD ");

                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
                Log.d("JSONParser is",is.toString());

            }else if(method == "GET"){
                Log.d("JSONParser","GET METHOD ");


                // request method is GET
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
                url += "?" + paramString;
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
                Log.d("JSONParser is",is.toString());

            }           


        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }
}
```

I tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11601433/jsonparser-do-not-update-mysql-database) but it does not work.

Comment: if you really get a success response, I'd guess your android app is transmitting a U_ID that doesn't exist in the database

Comment: It was my mistake at line  params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("U_ID", SessionSharedPrefences.getUserEmail(getApplicationContext())));         I am giving EmailId as UserID